# How to configure quarkus-oidc to use any other vert.x oauth2 providers other than KeycloakAuth?

Tags: vert.x, quarkus

I've been trying to set up a quarkus server to validate tokens from Azure Active Directory with quarkus-oidc. I noticed that under the hood quarkus-oidc uses vert.x oauth2 implementation, which has support for Azure Active Directory amongst other providers but unfortunately there seems to be no way to configure quarkus-oidc. The keycloak provider seems to be hardcoded in the class [OidcRecorder](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/904d7e0161ad29a4267c54cf0a584b3db59aa354/extensions/oidc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/runtime/OidcRecorder.java). Is there a way to bypass it? replace it? or configure it properly?